# Oracle: getting non unique duplicates with group by ... having count

Tags: oracle, group-by, duplicates, subquery

I'm trying to build a query that shows only non-unique duplicates. I've already built a query that shows all the records coming into consideration:

```
SELECT       tbl_tm.title, lp_index.starttime, musicsound.archnr
FROM         tbl_tm
INNER JOIN   musicsound on tbl_tm.fk_tbl_tm_musicsound = musicsound.pk_musicsound
INNER JOIN   lp_index ON musicsound.pk_musicsound = lp_index.fk_index_musicsound
INNER JOIN   plan ON lp_index.fk_index_plan = plan.pk_plan
WHERE        tbl_tm.FK_tbl_tm_title_type_music = '22' AND plan.airdate
             BETWEEN to_date ('15-01-13') AND to_date('17-01-13')
GROUP BY     tbl_tm.title, lp_index.starttime, musicsound.archnr 
HAVING COUNT (tbl_tm.title) > 0;
```

The corresponding result set looks like this:

```
title                   starttime   archnrr
============================================
Pumped up kicks         05:05:37    0616866
People Help The People  05:09:13    0620176
I can't dance           05:12:43    0600109
Locked Out Of Heaven    05:36:08    0620101
China in your hand      05:41:33    0600053
Locked Out Of Heaven    08:52:50    0620101
```

It gives me music titles played between a certain timespan along with their starting time and archive ID.

What I want to achieve is something like this:

```
title                  starttime    archnr
============================================
Locked Out Of Heaven   05:36:08     0620101
Locked Out Of Heaven   08:52:50     0620101
```

There would only be two columns left: both share the same title and archive number but differ in the time part. Increasing the 'HAVING COUNT' value will give me a zero-row
result set, since there aren't any entries that are exactly the same.

What I've found out so far is that the solution for this problem will most likely have a nested subquery, but I can't seem to get it done. Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Note: I'm on a Oracle 11g-server. My user has read-only privileges. I use SQL Developer on my workstation.

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this:

```
SELECT title, starttime, archnr
FROM (
SELECT title, starttime, archnr, count(*) over (partition by title) cnt
FROM (your_query))
WHERE cnt > 1
```

[Here is a sqlfiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f7405/5)

Comment: I tried it right away and repladed "your_query" with that whole statement that gives me all the records (i.e. the one with the triple inner join). It seems to work. Thanks alot for the quick answer!

Comment: Glad to be of some help. If you feel that this answer is a good one, please consider accepting it http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask